# transfering files in selected subdirectories with rsync

Tags: rsync

Hello everybody and sorry for the verbosity of this!

I have a server machine with a directory tree containing say 50,000 files in 1,000 directories; and a client machine where I do my everyday work. In the client I keep only a subset of the tree, say only 50 directories with 500 files.
When I want to save my work I use rsync from the client to the server, with a command like

`rsync -Otvriu -e "ssh" clientTreeHead/ server:serverTreeHead`

and this has worked for years. Now for some reason or other I have written more files on the server, in those 50 or so directories, and I would like to copy them to the client, but how? the line

`rsync -Otvriu -e "ssh" server:serverTreeHead/ clientTreeHead`

will transfer also lots of files in directories not needed on the client at this time. I tried making a script with 50 lines like

`rsync -Otviu -e "ssh" server:serverSubDir/ clientSubDir`

taking out the `r`(*). I thought, rsync would ignore *directories* in clientSubDir but still sync *files* in it, but it's not so: rsync ignores one level up, including clientSubDir, and my magic line does nothing at all.

Is there a way to adjourn my 50 directories? Thank you for any suggestion.

(*) because on the server, some of my 50 directories contain quite big subtrees that I do not want transferred